# How to find an entity and check if they have an "isAdmin" payload in JWT or not (custom Authentication)

Tags: jwt

I want to make my own simple role Auth, so this is what I'm dealing with:
first find the _id of the user: `const user = User.find({ '_id' : '_id'});`

I have to set up a JWT payload like: `const signed = jwt.sign({ "isAdmin": true, 'somekindofsecret'});`

Here I'm stuck. I want to see how can I make a function that checks the user's _id and checks if this person has an "isAdmin" payload in JWT or not and if yes let them enter the route if no tell them they're not authorized and redirect them somewhere else.

How to do these checks?

Comment: Corrected grammar and spelling and clarified question being asked.

Comment: @BobDalgleish further improved. ^_^